# Reformating an output print

Tags: linux, awk, formatting

In several different linux machines I have to count the number of tcp socket connections and their status for different ports.
At the end the printout might look like this.

```
49570 10.10.10.10:13062 ESTABLISHED    
  783 10.10.10.10:18080 CLOSE_WAIT    
  493 10.10.10.10:18082 CLOSE_WAIT  
  109 10.10.10.10:18080 SYN_RECV    
   17 10.10.10.10:15062 TIME_WAIT  
   15 10.10.10.10:15062 ESTABLISHED
```

The first column is the count, second ip:port, third the status.

What I want to do is to reformat the output so that it comes out like this

```
                13062   15062   18080   18082                           
ESTABLISHED     49570      15       0       0   
CLOSE_WAIT          0       0     783     493   
SYN_RECV            0       0     109       0   
TIME_WAIT           0      17       0       0
```

The ip, is different from machine to machine, there could be more ports as well, or more statuses, or less.
Is it possible to achieve this with awk. Does anyone have an example on how to get this.

Sorry I was having a hard time to paste the input/output result desired, it is as above now.
Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Your question may be a bit interesting but its not clear. could you please expand like what do you have now and how do you want to shape it ?

Comment: You want to Group By Statuses, What is the idea behind column size ? why there are four columns ? are four columns static ? So if it does why Time wait's 17 is not in the first column instead of the second ? You should describe result output's structure precisely.

Comment: Ok I understand little bit, the column size is the uniqe port count. Nevermind my question.

Comment: Got some problems editing the paste result, the number of ports is not fixed. It can be more, or even less, thanks.

Comment: So you want an output like the second one for each IP/host?

Comment: Yes that is correct Thomas, number of statuses and ports might change from machine to machne.  I would like to have the printout reformatted as above, per machine basis. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    sub(/.*:/,"",$2)
    ports[$2]
    statuses[$3]
    counts[$2,$3] = $1
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        maxWidth[i] = (length($i) > maxWidth[i] ? length($i) : maxWidth[i])
    }
}
END {
    statusWidth = maxWidth[3]
    otherWidth = (maxWidth[1] > maxWidth[2] ? maxWidth[1] : maxWidth[2]) + 2

    printf "%-*s", statusWidth, ""
    for (port in ports) {
        printf "%*s", otherWidth, port
    }
    print ""

    for (status in statuses) {
        printf "%-*s", statusWidth, status
        for (port in ports) {
            printf "%*d", otherWidth, counts[port,status]
        }
        print ""
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
             13062  15062  18080  18082
SYN_RECV         0      0    109      0
CLOSE_WAIT       0      0    783    493
ESTABLISHED  49570     15      0      0
TIME_WAIT        0     17      0      0
```

Comment: Well, I just quite my job last month so if that's a paying position then I'm all ears :-).

Comment: Thanks so much Ed, that works nicely. I am very grateful.

Comment: Hi Ed. sorry I am new here. I voted your answer as useful answer. I am not sure if I did it right though. I clicked on the ^ on your answer. Please let me know if that is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another **g**awk-solution

```
 awk -F"[: ]+" 'BEGIN{delim="\t"}
              {ports[$3]; status[$3][$4]=$1; st[$4]}
               END{str=delim 
                   for(key in ports){str=str""delim""key}
                   print str
                   for(k in st){
                      str =k
                      for (key in ports) {
                        str = str""delim""(status[key][k] ? status[key][k] : 0)
                      }
                      print str
                   }
                }' test.txt
```

Output (If you want white spaces instead of "\t" as delimiter, change `delim="\t"` to `delim=" "`):

```
        15062   13062   18080   18082
SYN_RECV    0   0   109 0
CLOSE_WAIT  0   0   783 493
ESTABLISHED 15  49570   0   0
TIME_WAIT   17  0   0   0
```

For this input (i.e., where there are no leading white spaces):

```
49570 10.10.10.10:13062 ESTABLISHED    
783 10.10.10.10:18080 CLOSE_WAIT    
493 10.10.10.10:18082 CLOSE_WAIT  
109 10.10.10.10:18080 SYN_RECV    
17 10.10.10.10:15062 TIME_WAIT  
15 10.10.10.10:15062 ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: You should mention that requires gawk 4.* due to the true 2d array and it wont work with the input file the OP posted since you are setting FS which disables awks default behavior of ignoring leading/trailing blanks. If you just add `{gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+/,"")}` at the start then it'd work on the OPs data.

Comment: @EdMorton: Thank you for the clarification! I have adapted my answer.

Comment: You should really say gawk 4.* though as earlier versions of gawk don't support the array syntax you are using (or just don't use that syntax and then it'll work in any awk). Also, you don't need to put null strings in string concatenation - for example `str=str""delim""key` can be written as just `str=str delim key`. FInally, `str = str""delim""(status[key][k] ? status[key][k] : 0)` can be written as just `str = str delim status[key][k]+0`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.